# Is it possible to have a variable that dynamically evaluates a command in bash?

Tags: bash

Basically, what I want is to have a variable that contains e.g. `$(some-command)`, so that it provides the result of `some-command` at the time it is expanded.

An example would help clarify what I mean.

Suppose I have some command `tell-svn-root` which prints to stdout the path of the most recent (i.e. deepest) ancestor of the current directory that contains a subdirectory `.svn`.

I would love to create a variable `SVNROOT` that always evaluates to the output of `tell-svn-root`.

`SVNROOT=$(tell-svn-root)` in `.bashrc` won't work because then `SVNROOT` will have a fixed value (namely the output of `tell-svn-root` when `.bashrc` was run).

A function that runs e.g. `cd $(tell-svn-root)` is also insufficient because I'd like to write commands like `cd $SVNROOT/my-app-src`.

I know that I can do `$(tell-svn-root)/my-app-src`, but typing those extra parentheses does slow things down a bit since it involves two characters up on the numbers row of the keyboard rather than just one.

I can't find a good answer for this, so I suspect it might be impossible.

Comment: If the main concern is to save typing when using `cd` then you could consider writing a `cd` function that translates `cd SVNROOT/...` to `builtin cd $(tell-svn-root)/...`.  You might want a `pushd` function too.  That saves typing a `$`, but would make life interesting if you ever had a directory called `SVNROOT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct: Precisely as-given (triggering code to be run whenever a specific variable's value is requested), the request is impossible.

That said, there are some workarounds; for example, you can have a function run every time the prompt is about to be printed (or before every command, if you were to implement a DEBUG trap), which updates your variable at that time.

Obviously, the performance impact is potentially nontrivial, and I would strongly suggest the extra verbosity involved in a function invocation; particularly insofar as safe practices for handling untrusted data are generally quite verbose, bash is not a language safe for use by those enamored with terseness.

```
update_variables() {
  if [[ $svnroot_for_PWD != "$PWD" ]]; then
    svnroot=$(tell-svn-root)
    svnroot_for_PWD=$PWD
  fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=update_variables
```

---

<sub>With respect to variable naming convention -- all-caps names are reserved for variables meaningful to the shell and other POSIX-defined tools, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed safe to use by user-defined code. See the relevant specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment and shell variables share the same namespace.</sub>

Comment: RE: being okay with verbosity. Fair enough. Of course, it's a little sad since the programming language is also basically my UI.